# change video resolution in sip mid call

Tags: android, sip, imsdroid

I want to change video resolution in sip mid call based on network speed.I tried a lot but failed 
    One of my trials is
    i reinvite second person with updated resolution
    code is

```
NgnAVSession session= NgnAVSession.getSession(new NgnPredicate<NgnAVSession>() {

                @Override
                public boolean apply(NgnAVSession session) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return session.isActive();
                }


            });
            //INgnConfigurationService configurationService = Engine.getInstance().getConfigurationService();
            MediaSessionMgr.defaultsSetPrefVideoSize(tmedia_pref_video_size_t.tmedia_pref_video_size_720p);
            //session.getMediaSessionMgr().defaultsSetPrefVideoSize(tmedia_pref_video_size_t.tmedia_pref_video_size_720p);

        session.makeCall(remoteUri);

but it does not work also.
```

Comment: re invitation with updated resolution causes default resolution for the next new call

Answer (score 0):

To be SIP specific - Please add the SDP from the Re-INVITE and the Client response in this case. This should help you understand why the rates don't change mid call.

As for the change staying for the next calls seems to application specific and not a protocol behavior.

Comment: Hi Rejesh,please make one thing clear can we change video resolution mid call

Comment: There is a SDP Spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6236 - that defines among other parameters- SAR which can be used to indicate the screen resolutions. If you building on something that support this spec you maybe able to leverage this spec to exchange the Screen Resolutions before and during the call.

Comment: how to use this specification if it supports